# Spring - How to reference a bean programmatically

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, code-injection

I have my application config set-up programmatically, and I am importing a bean like this:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource( value= { "classpath:myBean.xml"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
```

And in `myBean.xml` I have this:

```
  <bean id="myBeanId" class="my.domain.myBeanClass">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="my_session_factory" />
    <property name="someOtherProperty"...
  </bean>
```

This works fine and `sessionFactory` is injected into `myBeanClass`.

However if I try and instantiate that same bean programmatically, chanhing `ImportResource` to `Import`, I get "No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency..." error.

```
@Configuration
@Import(BeanConfig.class)
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
```

Bean Config Class:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig
{
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Bean(name="myBeanId")
  public MyBeanClass createMyBeanClass()
  {
    MyBeanClass mbc = new MyBeanClass();
    mbc.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    ....
    return mbc;
```

edit: The sessionFactory bean is definitely being created, if I add a required = false to @Autowired, and then manually inject the sessionFactory once everything is loaded. It works fine.

edit 2:
I don't have a web.xml, I am using servlet 3 so have declared everything programmatically. This is my web.xml equivalent

```
@Configuration
public class WalletInitialiser implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext aServletContext) throws ServletException
  {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext
      = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    mvcContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    mvcContext.scan("config.packages", "class.packages");
    aServletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(mvcContext));
    //add security filters, dispatcher to servlet, logback
```

I have my SessionFactory configured in another class, HibernateConfig in the config package, which is being picked up from

```
mvcContext.scan("config.packages", "class.packages");
```

Excerpt from this class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig
{
  @Bean(name="my_session_factory")
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean baseSessionFactory()
  {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb= new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    lsfb.setPackagesToScan("class.packages");
    lsfb.setAnnotatedPackages("class.packages");

    //add hibernate props for datasource
    return lsfb;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you turned on Annotation Based Configuration in Context (myBean.xml)??

Comment: Can you please also show how you have configured the AppConfig with your container(the web.xml entry for this AppConfig), also you probably have another config where you define the SessionFactory right, can you please show that config also

Comment: this is weird, you are using annoation driven config, but then importing a bean from an xml file. you as well drop he annotation java based conifg, as it is dependent on xml anyway. it is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: The first example I give, where I am using myBean.xml, is only because the annotation driven way wasn't working. I don't intend to leave that in. That was just an example to show that there is something different in the way `@Import` and `@ImportResource` treat things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be related to [How to make factoryBeans work...](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?82677-How-to-make-factoryBeans-work-with-javaConfig). Although it's not an exact match [Configuring Hibernate Session Factory](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/spring-framework/518-configuring-hibernate-sessionfactory-spring.html) may give insights to a work around.

I would suggest trying this:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
   @Autowired
   private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean;

   @Bean(name="myBeanId")
   public MyBeanClass createMyBeanClass() {
      MyBeanClass mbc = new MyBeanClass();
      mbc.setSessionFactory((SessionFactory) sessionFactoryBean.getObject());
     ....
     return mbc;
   }
}
```

There may be other ways to fix this, I didn't tracked the JIRA issues mentioned in the spring source forum, they may point to a "standard" way. Alternatively the Spring documentation may give some insight into the handling of FactoryBeans in java config.

Comment: That seemed to do it. Good links also. Thank you very much.